# Not able to click on "SAVE" Bbutton in Python Selenium - Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, chrome-web-driver

Hi I do have the below codes for the Save Button that needs to be clicked using Python Selenium.

```
1 <button ngcontent-jkv-c423-" " type="button" mat-raised-button=" " id="btnSave" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-none mat_animation-noopable ng-star-inserted" data-dtname="Work.save"> 
2 <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
3 <span ngcontent-jkv-c423="" data-dtname="Work.save">
4 <i _ngcontent-jkv-c423-"" aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-save">
5 </i> 
6 "Save "
7 </span>
8 </span>
9 <span matripple=" " class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple">
10 </span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span>
11 </button>
```

T tried the following codes:

```
1 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Save ')]").click()
2 driver.find_element_by_class_name("fas fa-save").click()
3 driver.find_element_by_class_name("//span[@data-dtname='Work.save']").click()
```

But all the above codes are throwing errors.

Is there any alternative ways to do this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exceptions do you see? can you share a link to that page?

Answer (score 1):

`Save` looks like a **text node** so, you **can not** use this xpath  :

```
//span[contains(text(),'Save ')]
```

your `2nd attempt` looks invalid cause :-

class name with space are not supported.

and `3rd attempt :-`

```
find_element_by_class_name("//span[@data-dtname='WorkQueue.save']")
```

you are passing `xpath`, in `class name.`

so, Why not `id`  ?

```
driver.find_element_by_id('btnSave').click()
```

**Update 1 :**

can you launch browser in full screen mode like this.

```
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: i tried that too `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <button ngcontent-uks-c423="" type="button" mat-raised-button="" id="btnSave" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-none mat-animation-noopable ng-star-inserted" data-dtname="Work.save">...</button> is not clickable at point (916, 18). Other element would receive the click: <div class="cdk-overlay-backdrop cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing"></div>` but getting this exception

Comment: Are you launching browser in full screen  ?

Comment: no... is that the problem?..let me try putting it in full screen

Comment: yes, it could be fix for the above exception

Comment: no..that is not the problem.. im still getting the same exception. Is there any other method to access the SAVE Button???

Comment: I have updated above  how you can launch the browser in full screen, Did you try ? if that does not work, we need to use ActionChains class

Comment: is it because of the 4th line in the code : `aria-hidden="true"`.

Comment: Is it visible in UI ? How do you click on this button manually ?

Comment: i tried with `driver.maximize_window()` but still getting the same exception. Yes the buton is vilible in UI and am able to click it manually.

Comment: Can you try this code :- `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_id('btnSave')).click().perform()` to use this you will need to import this :- `from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains`

Comment: Hi i didn't get any exception this time, but still the code is not clicking on the Save Button.

Comment: The xpath for the button is :`//*[@id="btnSave"]`

Comment: yes, I have given you id, but `//*[@id="btnSave"]` is the equivalent xpath. if the xpath works then id should also work

Comment: Xpath is also not working... and ID also not working. im not getting why.

Comment: Where is this button located in UI ?

Comment: Hi i did some alterations to the code and this works perfectly. As far as i understood another element is covering the element which i wanted to click , so i did the below code: `save_ele=driver.findelement_by_xpath("**full xpath of the element**)`
`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",save_ele)`
the adove code works

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood another element is covering the element which i wanted to click , so i did the below code:

```
save_ele=driver.findelement_by_xpath("**full xpath of the element**)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",save_ele)
```

This is working fine for me.